# Append Multiple Images to a PDF Page with LEADTOOLS

Tags: leadtools-sdk

Is there some way to add multiple (2, 3 or 4) images to the same page of a PDF file using the LEADTOOLS C API?

The `L_SaveBitmap()` function takes a `SAVEFILEOPTION` parameter, where the `PageNumber` can be set, but setting this to a value greater than 1 causes a new page to be appended. Instead, a value of 1 or 0 causes the file to be overwritten.

The `L_SaveFile()` function performs similarly; setting the `SAVEFILE_MULTIPAGE` flag causes a new page to be always appended.

The `L_PdfComp..()` functions don't seem to be capable of handling pages at all.

Do the `MRC` functions support handling of pages, i.e. specify which page each image will be stored in? Also, is the file generated of standard PDF format, or it is LEAD-specific?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the part about “is the file generated of standard PDF format, or it is LEAD-specific”, any PDF file saved by any and all LEADTOOLS functions is a standard PDF file, and it should be possible to open it using any standard PDF viewer.
However, if you wish to append or replace pages using L_SaveBitmap(), the existing PDF file must be a raster-based PDF similar to the output of L_SaveBitmap() itself.

To work with more general types of PDF, other LEADTOOLS functions can be used, such as the .NET [PDFFile class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/pdf/pdffile.html) and [PDFDocument class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/pdf/pdfdocument.html).

The C/C++ code below performs overwriting (creating a new file), appending and replacing a specific page. It also shows how to place 2 images inside a single PDF page.
The code segments can be combined into one function to test them with any 4 input image files.

First, create a file with one page, overwriting it if it exists:

```
// Create file with first page
BITMAPHANDLE page1 = { 0 };
L_LoadBitmap(page1_file, &page1, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);
page1.XResolution = page1.YResolution = BITMAPHEIGHT(&page1) / 11; //set the DPI to cause 11 inch height.
L_SaveBitmap(outputPdf_file, &page1, FILE_RAS_PDF_LZW, 24, 0, NULL);
L_FreeBitmap(&page1);
```

Next, load an image and append it as a second page to the same PDF file:

```
// Append second page
BITMAPHANDLE page2 = { 0 };
L_LoadBitmap(page2_file, &page2, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);
SAVEFILEOPTION SaveOptions = { 0 };
L_GetDefaultSaveFileOption(&SaveOptions, sizeof SAVEFILEOPTION);
SaveOptions.PageNumber = 2;
page2.XResolution = page2.YResolution = BITMAPHEIGHT(&page2) / 11; //set the DPI to cause 11 inch height.
L_SaveBitmap(outputPdf_file, &page2, FILE_RAS_PDF_LZW, 24, 0, &SaveOptions);
L_FreeBitmap(&page2);
```

Finally, load 2 images, combine them into one image and **replace** the first page with the image combined from the newly-loaded 2 images:

```
BITMAPHANDLE page2_1 = { 0 }, page2_2 = { 0 };
// Load 2 iamges for one page
L_LoadBitmap(page2_1_file, &page2_1, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);
L_LoadBitmap(page2_2_file, &page2_2, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);

L_UINT w = max(BITMAPWIDTH(&page2_1), BITMAPWIDTH(&page2_2));
L_UINT h = BITMAPHEIGHT(&page2_1) + BITMAPHEIGHT(&page2_2);
BITMAPHANDLE combinedPage = { 0 };
// Create empty bitmap
L_CreateBitmap(&combinedPage, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, TYPE_CONV, w, h, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, BOTTOM_LEFT, NULL, 0);
// Copy the first image into the empty bitmap
L_CombineBitmap(&combinedPage, 0, 0, BITMAPWIDTH(&page2_1), BITMAPHEIGHT(&page2_1), &page2_1, 0, 0, CB_DST_0 | CB_OP_ADD | CB_RAWCOMBINE, 0);
L_FreeBitmap(&page2_1);
// Copy the second image below the first image
L_CombineBitmap(&combinedPage, 0, BITMAPHEIGHT(&page2_1), BITMAPWIDTH(&page2_2), BITMAPHEIGHT(&page2_2), &page2_2, 0, 0, CB_DST_0 | CB_OP_ADD | CB_RAWCOMBINE, 0);
L_FreeBitmap(&page2_2);
SaveOptions.PageNumber = 1;
SaveOptions.Flags |= ESO_REPLACEPAGE; // add the replace flag to put the combined image instead of the old page1
combinedPage.XResolution = combinedPage.YResolution = BITMAPHEIGHT(&combinedPage) / 11; //set the DPI to cause 11 inch height.
L_SaveBitmap(outputPdf_file, &combinedPage, FILE_RAS_PDF_LZW, 24, 0, &SaveOptions);
L_FreeBitmap(&combinedPage);
```

**The following part was added after the answer got accepted, to address a comment:**

It is possible to insert multiple images into a single PDF page without combining them first, but not using the L_SaveBitmap() function. Instead, the Document Writer functions need to be used as shown in the following code sample.

The code below loads 2 images and puts them into an EMF memory file. It then draws an ellipse on top of them to show that any Windows GDI graphics object can be added (for example, you can add text using TextOut() or other GDI functions). After that, the EMF page is saved as PDF using LEADTOOLS Document Writer.

```
BITMAPHANDLE image1 = { 0 }, image2 = { 0 };
// Load 2 iamges for one page
L_LoadBitmap(image1_file, &image1, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);
L_LoadBitmap(image2_file, &image2, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 24, ORDER_BGR, NULL, NULL);
L_UINT w = max(BITMAPWIDTH(&image1), BITMAPWIDTH(&image2));
L_UINT h = BITMAPHEIGHT(&image1) + BITMAPHEIGHT(&image2);

// Create a memory metafile and paint both bitmaps in it
HDC hdcEmf = CreateEnhMetaFile(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
Rectangle(hdcEmf, 0, 0, w, h);

RECT rc1 = { 0, 0, BITMAPWIDTH(&image1), BITMAPHEIGHT(&image1) };
L_PaintDC(hdcEmf, &image1, NULL, NULL, &rc1, NULL, SRCCOPY);
L_FreeBitmap(&image1);

RECT rc2 = { 0, BITMAPHEIGHT(&image1), BITMAPWIDTH(&image2), BITMAPHEIGHT(&image1) + BITMAPHEIGHT(&image2) };
L_PaintDC(hdcEmf, &image2, NULL, NULL, &rc2, NULL, SRCCOPY);
L_FreeBitmap(&image2);

Ellipse(hdcEmf, w / 4, h / 4, w * 3 / 4, h * 3 / 4);

HENHMETAFILE hemf = CloseEnhMetaFile(hdcEmf);

DOCWRTPDFOPTIONS pdf = { 0 };
L_DOUBLE dTextScale = 0.5;
DOCUMENTWRITER_HANDLE hDocument = 0;
DOCWRTEMFPAGE Page = { 0 };
pdf.PdfProfile = DOCWRTPDFPROFILE_PDF;
pdf.Options.uStructSize = sizeof(pdf);
pdf.Options.nDocumentResolution = 300;
// Setup empty page size based on images size
pdf.Options.dEmptyPageWidth = w / 300.0;
pdf.Options.dEmptyPageHeight = h / 300.0;
pdf.Options.nEmptyPageResolution = 300;

L_DocWriterInit(&hDocument, outputPdf_file, DOCUMENTFORMAT_PDF, &pdf, NULL, NULL);
Page.hEmf = hemf;
Page.pdwTextScale = &dTextScale;
L_DocWriterAddPage(hDocument, DOCWRTPAGETYPE_EMF, (L_VOID*)&Page);
L_DocWriterFinish(hDocument);

DeleteEnhMetaFile(hemf);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no direct way to add two images to the same PDF Page using the LEAD C API, and I have to work around it by creating a new image and copy the the two images. This is what I needed to know.

Comment: Modified the answer to address the part about adding multiple images to the PDF page without combining them into a single bitmap.